# Best way to run Qunit tests under flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, qunit

I have a set of QUnit tests on an html page that I need to run. As this test refer to javascript functions which hit the server with AJAX requests, I cannot run the test Html file straight from the file system without getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/_get_stats. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

On the server, I have a Flask app. I thought about writing a view to serve my test html, an thus bypass the access-control, but I wonder if this is the recommended way to solve this. any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have adopted is to create a view like so:

```
@app.route("/_test")
def test():
    return render_template('test.html')
```

it requires the server to be running, but that's the whole point in my case.